# How to remove key from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove keys from my arrays, and array be like

```
Array ( [0] => 23/2 [1] => KG Halli [2] => D' Souza Layout [3] => Sampangi Rama Nagar [4] => Bengaluru [5] => Bangalore Urban [6] => Karnataka [7] => India [8] => 560001 )
```

and i need it as

23/2, KG Halli, D' Souza Layout, Sampangi Rama Nagar, Bengaluru, Banglore Urban

Comment: Use the `implode()` function. ex: `implode(', ', $your_arr);`

Comment: Do you want to print or echo the values? Or you want to use it in another function?

Comment: I just need print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php implode() function is the answer to your question

You can use implode to make your array values as a string and attach each value with any separator i.e. ',' or a space.

```
implode(', ', ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$required_str = implode(',',$array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$yourString = implode(", ", $yourArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

use string function `implode()`

```
$arr = array('23/2','KG Halli',"D' Souza Layout",'Sampangi Rama Nagar' ,'Bengaluru','Bangalore Urban','Karnataka', 'India',560001);
echo implode(",",$arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  **implode()** php function to make an array to string

Just like this

```
$array=['id'=>12,'no'=>1234]
$String = implode(", ", $array);//it give o/p as "12,1234"
```

Or if you want array with no key value then you can use **array_values()**
Just like this

```
$array=array_values($array);//it give o/p as [12,1234]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function of PHP.

Example: `implode(', ', $your_arr);`